# Difference between query() in ContentProvider and ContentResolver classes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-context, android-contentresolver

I'm new to android. Right now I'm doing Content Providers. I'm following the "Pro android 3" book. From there I have implemented the `BookProvider` example. I have implemented the `insert,update,delete` functions in `BookProvider` class which extends `ContentProvider` class.But then while using the functions, there I have used:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
cr.delete(uri,contentValues);
```

My doubt is in what way the methods that I have written in the `BookProvider` class communicates with the `ContentResolver` class ...

Also someone please example the basic definitions, difference and relation between `Context`,`ContentProvider` and `ContentResolver` classes

One more doubt is that in some examples they have explicitly casted context objects into Activity objects ... How are Activity and Context classes related?

Answer (score 2):

A `Context` contains information about the context where an `Activity`, `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` is running. All those classes inherit directly or indirectly from `Context`. So it stands that all `Activity`ies are `Context`s, but only some `Context`s are `Activity`ies

When you define a `ContentProvider` you specify one or more base uris for the elements it can handle. The `ContentResolver` job is to dispatch your commands to a `ContentProvider`, based on the uri you provide.

Comment: Thanq ... Is it true that the ContentResolver also inherits from the ContentProvider ... ??

Comment: BroadcastReceiver does not inherit directly or indirectly from Context.